# Install mutillidae and DVWA on the same machine?

Tags: server, webserver, database

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, I installed mutillidae and it worked perfectly, but now I wanted to install DVWA and it also worked, but when I entered mutillidae again I got this error: " The database server at 127.0.0.1 appears to be offline. "

[image]

I tried to change the DVWA port to another and it didn't work. Is it possible to have these two pentesting labs on the same machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I solved it, at first I had mutillidae installed which used myslq, then I installed dvwa which uses mariadb, so I don't know if I'm fine but when installing mariadb(versions 10.6 or higher) it dumps the mysql database, so it got misconfigured or something like that, so I did the following:

If you have a password in mysql, put this (in my case it was 'mutillidae'):

```
mysql -u root -p{ your root password here}
```

Otherwise just with it:

```
sudo mysql;
```

and the following is this:

```
USE mysql;
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED VIA mysql_native_password;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit
```

At least that's what I did, but before I didn't have a database called 'mutillidae', only the one of 'dvwa', so I created a database with the name of mutillidae.

In my `'database-config.inc'` file located in the path `/var/www/html/mutillidae/includes`, I have the following:

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'mutillidae');
define('DB_PORT', 3306);
?>
```

In my DVWA `'config.inc.php'` file located at the path `/var/www/html/DVWA/config`, I have the following:

```
$_DVWA = array();
$_DVWA[ 'db_server' ]   = '127.0.0.1';
$_DVWA[ 'db_database' ] = 'dvwa';
$_DVWA[ 'db_user' ]     = 'dvwa';
$_DVWA[ 'db_password' ] = 'p@ssw0rd';
$_DVWA[ 'db_port'] = '3306';
```